# Show image from url in uiimageview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I try to show a image in my iphone app but it doesn't show. I connect in IB and I check to show a local image, it workd good. I also check the url from image and it is ok. I use the next code:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: aVideo.urlThumbnail];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; 
imageView.image = image;
```

and

```
//Video.h
NSString *urlThumbnail;
```

and this is my code on the view.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"URLTHUMBNAIL: %@", aVideo.urlThumbnail); 
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString: aVideo.urlThumbnail];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; 
    imageView.image = image;
}
```

NSLog getts on console

```
URLTHUMBNAIL: http://147.83.74.180/thumbnails/56.jpg
```

The connections on IB are ok, cause I can display a local image using next code on the same IBAction

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"barret" ofType:@"png"]];
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Check your IBoutlets again, or post more code.

Comment: The IBoutlet is ok. And I write this on ViewDidAppear.

Answer (score 1):

It can be very helpful to `NSLog()` yourself some notes about what's really in your variables. If you really do have everything hooked up right in IB, it could be that `aVideo.urlThumbnail` isn't getting set. I'd like to see that value in the console right before creating your NSURL with it.

Comment: I add the test on the question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, since `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:` accesses the network, you should consider doing that in the background.  Otherwise, your UI may become unresponsive.

You should consider adding some additional logging to check the value of `imageData` and `image`.  Also, you can call `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` to see if that's the source of the failure.